# PHP/MySQL - Validating Usernames with Exceptions for Additional Characters

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I've created an athletic league website with dynamic schedules and standings using PHP and MySQL.  One of the basic functions of the website is for schools to select a game on the schedule that's already been played and log-in to report the score.  You can see an example of the score reporting page below:

http://www.parochialathleticleague.org/report_score.html?league=test_league&game_id=5&away_team=St.%20Polycarp&home_team=St.%20Columban

After several months of work, everything seems to be working just right.  However, I realized one important oversight this morning, just before the schedules for the new season are about to go live:

Some of our schools have multiple teams in each division because they have extra students.  So, for example, there may be a St. Barbara AND a St. Barbara #2 participating in the same league and/or division.  Sometimes, there are as many as three of four teams from the larger schools.

This is a problem because the validation code that I've written checks the school usernames to make sure they match the master school user accounts in the MySQL database before being allowed to report a score.  Therefore, St. Barbara would not be authorized to report a score for their St. Barbara #2 team, even though they belong to the same school!  I don't want to create separate user accounts for every team belonging to that school, so I need to modify the code in some way. I would like St. Barbara to be able to log-in with the same username for all of their different teams, regardless of whether or not there are additional characters at the end (if that makes sense).

Here's the function from my script that validates the username (school) to make sure they're one of the two teams participating in the game in question:

```
// Validate the school:
if (empty($_POST['school'])) {
    echo "You forgot to enter your school.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} elseif ($_POST['school'] != $_POST['away_team'] && $_POST['school'] != $_POST['home_team']) {
    echo "Your school does not match one of the two on file for this game.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} else {
    $school = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['school']));
    $validate = 'true';
}
```

Next, here's the function that later validates that the username and password match one of the records in the database:

```
// If all conditions are met, process the form:
if ($validate != 'false') {
    $q1 = "SELECT school_id FROM user_schools WHERE (school_name='$school' AND pass='$pass')";
    $r1 = mysqli_query($db, $q1);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($r1);
    if ($num == 1) { 
// ***a whole bunch of other stuff that I'm omitting because it's not relevant
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to add an "addendum", so to speak, to the code that would make an exception for schools that have multiple teams?  Sort of like:

```
elseif ($_POST['school'] == $_POST['away_team'] **MINUS ADDITIONAL INTEGERS AT THE END** || $_POST['school'] == $_POST['home_team'] **MINUS ADDITIONAL INTEGERS AT THE END**) {
        $validate = 'true';
    }
```

Sorry for the whole long spiel.  Just wanted to make sure I explained it properly!  Any thoughts?  Your feedback is much appreciated.

EDIT - Here's the entire script for those that were interested:

```
<?php

// Connect to the database:
require ('../mysqli_connect.php');

// Validate the school:
if (empty($_POST['school'])) {
    echo "You forgot to enter your school.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} elseif ($_POST['school'] != $_POST['away_team'] && $_POST['school'] != $_POST['home_team']) {
    echo "Your school does not match one of the two on file for this game.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} else {
    $school = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['school']));
    $validate = 'true';
}

// Validate the password:
if (empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    echo "You forgot to enter your password.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} else {
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['pass']));
    $validate = 'true';
}

// Validate the away score:
if (!isset($_POST['away_score'])) {
    echo "You forgot to enter the away score.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} elseif (!is_numeric($_POST['away_score'])) {
    echo "You entered an invalid score for the away team.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} else {
    $away_score_confirm = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_score']));
    $validate = 'true';
}

// Validate the home score:
if (!isset($_POST['away_score'])) {
    echo "You forgot to enter the home score.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} elseif (!is_numeric($_POST['$home_score']) && $_POST['$home_score'] < 0 ) {
    echo "You entered an invalid score for the home team.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} else {
    $home_score_confirm = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['home_score']));
    $validate = 'true';
}

// Determine the winner and loser, and set variables:
if ($_POST['away_score'] > $_POST['home_score']) {
    $winner = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_team']));
    $winner_score = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_score']));
    $loser = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['home_team']));
    $loser_score = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['home_score']));
    $tie = 'no';
} else if ($_POST['away_score'] < $_POST['home_score']) {
    $winner = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['home_team']));
    $winner_score = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['home_score']));
    $loser = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_team']));
    $loser_score = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_score']));
    $tie = 'no';
} else if ($_POST['away_score'] == $_POST['home_score']) {
    $tie = 'yes';
    $tie1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_team']));
    $tie2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['home_team']));
    $tie_score = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_score']));
}

// Declare remaining hidden inputs as variables:
$league = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['league']);
$game_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['game_id']);

// If all conditions are met, process the form:
if ($validate != 'false') {
    $q1 = "SELECT school_id FROM user_schools WHERE (school_name='$school' AND pass='$pass')";
    $r1 = mysqli_query($db, $q1);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($r1);
    if ($num == 1) {
        // Get the game ID:
        $q2 = "SELECT $game_id FROM $league";
        $r2 = mysqli_query($db, $q2);
        // Get the row for the game ID:
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r2, MYSQLI_NUM);
        // Perform an UPDATE query to modify the game scores:
        $q3 = "UPDATE $league SET home_score='$home_score_confirm', away_score='$away_score_confirm' WHERE game_id=$row[0]";        
        $r3 = mysqli_query($db, $q3);
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($db) == 1) {
            $confirm = 'true';
        } else {
            $confirm = 'false';
        }

        // Update the winning team in the standings:
        $q4 = "SELECT school_id FROM test_league_standings WHERE school_name='$winner'";
        $r4 = mysqli_query($db, $q4);
        // Get the row for the school:
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r4, MYSQLI_NUM);
        $q5 = "UPDATE test_league_standings SET games=games + 1, win=win + 1, pts_for=pts_for + '$winner_score', pts_against=pts_against + '$loser_score' WHERE school_id=$row2[0]";
        $r5 = mysqli_query($db, $q5);
        $q6 = "UPDATE test_league_standings SET pct=(win / games), avg_for=(pts_for / games), avg_against=(pts_against / games) WHERE school_id=$row2[0]";
        $r6 = mysqli_query($db, $q6);
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($db) == 1) {
            $confirm = 'true';
        } else {
            $confirm = 'false';
        }

        // Update the losing team in the standings:
        $q7 = "SELECT school_id FROM test_league_standings WHERE school_name='$loser'";
        $r7 = mysqli_query($db, $q7);
        // Get the row for the school:
        $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($r7, MYSQLI_NUM);
        $q8 = "UPDATE test_league_standings SET games=games + 1, loss=loss+1, pts_for=pts_for + '$loser_score', pts_against=pts_against + '$winner_score' WHERE school_id=$row3[0]";
        $r8 = mysqli_query($db, $q8);
        $q9 = "UPDATE test_league_standings SET pct=(win / games), avg_for=(pts_for / games), avg_against=(pts_against / games) WHERE school_id=$row3[0]";
        $r9 = mysqli_query($db, $q9);
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($db) == 1) {
            $confirm = 'true';
        } else {
            $confirm = 'false';
        }

        if ($confirm != 'false') {
            header("Location: schedules_test.html?league=" . $league);
        } else {
            echo "The scores could not be reported due to a system error. Apologies for the inconvenience. If this problem continues, please contact us directly.";
        }

    } else {
        echo "Your school and password combination do not match those on file for this game.";
    }       
}

mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

Comment: You'd be a lot better off using the placeholders feature of `mysqli` and the [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method to add data than using string interpolation. You're one mistake away from a gigantic SQL injection bug that could destroy your application without that isolation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'll definitely look into that.  For what little it may be worth, I do run validation in the script for both score, using isnumeric to try to thwart SQL injection.

Comment: Everything needs to be escaped regardless of how much scrubbing or cleaning you *think* you've done. It's your last line of defense and it better be a good one. Placeholders usually make your SQL code a lot easier to read as a bonus.

Comment: I just realized that I am, in fact, using mysqli_real_escape_string and trim elsewhere in the script before submitting the values to the database.  I've posted the entire code above.  Is that along the lines of what you were referring to?

Comment: Your queries should look like `WHERE school_name=?` and then bind the value of `$loser` in there after the fact. This makes for much more resilient query code, it's significantly harder to make a mistake if there's nothing interpolated in your query string. You're using `mysqli` just like `mysql_query`, which is a mistake. The [object oriented interface](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) is a lot better than the procedural one, so I'd recommend using that instead. It makes your code a lot more clear.

Comment: Since you added the entire script, I see problems already. 1) The `$validate` variable depends entirely on the last validated field, in this case "home_score" (this validation check is messed up as well; the key is either 'away_score' or '$home_score' instead of 'home_score'). If that field is valid, everything else is assumed to be because you set `$validate = 'true';`. 2) Your UPDATE queries have potential injection vulnerabilities if `$row[0]`, `$row[2]`, or `$row[3]` are not guaranteed to be numeric. They might not always be in the future. 3) Same validation problem for `$confirm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment I'm going to assume that you're validating that `$_POST['away_team']` and `$_POST['home_team']` are valid and correct.

If you just want to check that `$_POST['away_team']` *begins with* the string `$_POST['school']`, you can use the [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) function:

```
elseif (strpos($_POST['away_team'], $_POST['school']) === 0 || strpos($_POST['home_team'], $_POST['school'])) {
    echo "Your school does not match one of the two on file for this game.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
}
```

I'd like to assent to tadman's comment about SQL injection. Even if you aren't willing to rewrite your application to take advantage of the superior methods of injecting data into queries, you **absolutely** should escape your data when you run your query. Do **not** escape it anywhere else. If you do, eventually you will forget to escape it and it won't be as obvious as it should be. For example:

```
if ($validate != 'false') {
    $q1 = sprintf(
        "SELECT school_id FROM user_schools WHERE (school_name='%s' AND pass='%s')",
        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['school']),
        mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass'])
    );
    $r1 = mysqli_query($db, $q1);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($r1);
    if ($num == 1) { 
// ***a whole bunch of other stuff that I'm omitting because it's not relevant
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I goofed on the echo portion of that code when pasting.  I do want to validate that they're correct, not false.  This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.  Will test it out!

Comment: `sprintf` is a poor substitute for `bind_param`.

Comment: True, but it's immediately better than what he's doing. To use `bind_param` you need to be using prepared statements, which everybody should anyway, but it's a more difficult change. If the architecture assumes all queries are adequately represented by strings, the change might be impossible without a more thorough redesign.

Comment: @meustrus If it helps any, I just posted the entire script so you can see the process and security measures I put in place. Any suggestions are welcome, if you feel so inclined. Thank you, again.

Comment: @meustrus It's not really a difficult change. It's just an extra line or two depending on how you do it.